# cocos2d-x: CRUD 2d array from another class

Tags: c++, arrays, cocos2d-x, multidimensional-array

I have 3 class, GamePlay, Util, Panel
In GamePlay i have a lot of Panel as a matrix
I want to create an array to store type of each panel. type is int (for easy).
So i want to store that array in Util then i can update and get value from GamePlay and Panel too.

I tried with static int * array[100]; but it error.

Please help me. or tell me the best way to do it.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make all classes as a child on `CCObject` and then you can store their objects in `CCArray`

e.g. Your class `Panel` would be:

```
class Panel : CCObject
{
};
```

Storing `Panel` in `CCArray` :

```
CCArray* array = CCArray::create();

Panel* panel = new Panel();

array.addObject(panel);
```

Comment: Vikas Patidar: i found the better way for my app. Anyway, thank you very much. I hope to receive a lot of your help in future.